# Добавление опций компилятору извне cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Как передать `cmake` флаги компилятора, при этом не перезаписывая объявленные в `CMakeLists`, а добавляя к ним? Нужно изменить стандартную библиотеку для компиляции компилятором `clang`. В `CMakeLists` указаны `-Wall` и т.п. флаги, а внешне хочу добавить к ним `-stdlib=libc++` (стандартная библиотека от `llvm` вместо `libstdc++` от `gcc`).

Пробую вызывать `cmake` с опцией `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++"`, однако появляются ошибки. Скорее всего потому что `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` не подставляется в таком контексте. Если вызывать просто `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"`, то по идее перезаписываются опции из `CMakeLists` и варнингов не будет. Как быть?

Comment: Такие вещи прописываются внутри CMake файла, а не передаются извне. Т.е. возможно какой-то способ найти и можно, но это всё равно будет костылём.

Answer (score 1):

В `CMakeLists.txt` нужно правильно прописать установку переменных, упомянув предыдущее значение:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

После этого ни каких дополнительных телодвижений совершать не надо. Просто передать `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="<свои флаги>"` `cmake`'у и всё будет работать.

Если флаги устанавливаются не таким способом, то изменить их разумными средствами невозможно.

**Немного деталей как это работает**

При вызове `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=<...>` устанавливается *кешированная* переменная, которая сохраняется в `CMakeCache.txt`. В дальнейшем при выполнение команды `set` из `CMakeLists.txt` её значение будет использовано и дописано в необходимое место. При этом команда `set` устанавливает *локальную* переменную, значение которой не сохраняется, но применяется для последующих команд, как например `add_executable`.

Answer (score 0):

[`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) изначально инициализируется переменными окружения.

- CMAKE_C_FLAGS инициализируется значением переменой окружения CFLAGS
- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS инициализируется значением переменой окружения CXXFLAGS
- CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS инициализируется значением переменой окружения CUDAFLAGS
- CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS инициализируется значением переменой окружения FFLAGS

Таким образом можно написать что-то вроде

```
cmake -E env CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" cmake #...
```